# Adding an image on java based on a type

Tags: java, image

I'm writing code for a simple game and right now I'm working on the class that adds the images to the program. It's a simple game that includes dots and there are three primary types: available, selected, and dot.

Can you please guide me through a way to add an image based on each type of the dot? In my method I have defined "type" as int.

So far this is what I have:

```
public void setType(int type) {

    if(available){
        type = AVAILABLE;
        icons[type] = new ImageIcon(DotButton.class.getResource("/data/ball-0.png")); 
    }
    if(selected){
        type = SELECTED;
        icons[type] = new ImageIcon(DotButton.class.getResource("/data/ball-1.png"));
    }
    if(dot){
        type = DOT;
        icons[type] = new ImageIcon(DotButton.class.getResource("/data/ball-2.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You might separately want to check out [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) ... `public void setType(ImageType type)` where `public enum ImageType { AVAILABLE, SELECTED, DOT; }` instead of `int type`

Answer (score 0):

You read all of the images once and store them in a List.

Something like this.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImageTypeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ImageTypeTest().execute();
    }

    public void execute() {
        List<ImageType> imageTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
        imageTypeList.add(new ImageType(AVAILABLE, DotButton.getClass()
                .getResource("/data/ball-0.png")));
        imageTypeList.add(new ImageType(SELECTED, DotButton.getClass()
                .getResource("/data/ball-1.png")));
        imageTypeList.add(new ImageType(DOT, DotButton.getClass().getResource(
                "/data/ball-2.png")));
    }

    public class ImageType {
        private final int type;
        private final Image image;

        public ImageType(int type, Image image) {
            this.type = type;
            this.image = image;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public Image getImage() {
            return image;
        }

    }

}
```